# Bot? check if a domain name is availible?

Tags: automation, domain-name, domain-registration

I am trying to get a 3 letter domain with .net or .org and it seems like EVERY combination is taken. Is there a way i can get a list of domains available? perhaps with a bot? (i'll write it if i need to)

Comment: I can't find it, but I remember seeing an article on slashdot or something a few years ago saying that all of the 3 letter domains where used for .com, .net, and .org.

Comment: com are all gone, but there are some nets and orgs. http://www.3la.org/toc.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On windows you can use

```
nslookup <domain name>
```

Example:

```
C:\>nslookup abc.com
Server:  pd1nsc1.st.vc.XXXXX.net
Address:  64.59.144.XX

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:    abc.com
Address:  199.181.132.250
```

Example no domain:

```
C:\>nslookup abceeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee.com
Server:  pd1nsc1.st.vc.XXXXX.net
Address:  64.59.144.XX

*** pd1nsc1.st.vc.shawcable.net can't find abceeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee.com: Non-ex
istent domain
```

Every 3 letter domain has been registered on .com, .net, .org... I believe its the same with 4 letter domains, i think there is still some 5 letter domains left.

Answer (score 2):

Asking for all three-letter domains from the .com, .net, and .org servers should take about 17576 queries to each, so 52,728 total.  Should take about 15 minutes to write the script, and a few minutes to run.

It won't get you exactly what you want, as not being in DNS does not exactly mean it is free.  However, it's a good start.

Comment: I have no idea how to properly check if a domain is registered or not.

Comment: Use a registrar lookup, perhaps 'whois' or the like.  Most places that let you register domains will let you query interactively.  Asking the DNS servers, however, will be a fast filter to know what MIGHT be free.

Answer (score 1):

You should expect that **all** three-letter domains are taken and many are available for sale. [Google is your friend (or perhaps not).](http://www.google.com/search?q=three+letter+domains)